# How to enable SSL on IIS 7 / Windows 7 64bit

Tags: iis-7, ssl

I'm trying to enable SSL in IIS 7 on my dev machine using a self signed cert.  This is turning out to be quite frustrating.

I have followed [THIS](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx) guide and several others that are almost identical. The configuration goes ok, but when I try and navigate to the website I get various errors.

http://localhost/index.htm - Results in HTTP Error 404 - Not Found.

https://localhost/index.htm - Results in Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.

If I go into IIS and remove the https binding from the website then it works as expected (in http only obviously).

I'm gussing that there is something that needs to be set up / configured / installed in windows before this will work?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Martyn
Do you have any URL Rewrite rules defined for the particular site or any redirects?
Did you try to issue another self signed certificate? Maybe the certificate has errors.
Is the Require SSL option under SSL Settings for the particular site disabled?
Try to connect from another computer to your dev machine and sniff the traffic with Wireshark. There you can see if IIS returns something to the client.

Comment: I saw the same behavior until I rebooted the machine after first installing the cert. I'm not sure what process specifically needed to be restarted, but HTH.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't need to reboot, it looks like IIS is not responding for some reason. Do you have Skype installed by any chance? It is unfortunately one of the most common reasons we see issues with ports.

So do this:

1. Open IIS Manager, and select the server
2. Click in the Sites page and make sure Default Web Site is Started.
3. If it is not running click Start

Also to troubleshoot in case it is a port issue:

1. OPen an elevated command prompt and type
2. netstat -ano
3. Search in there for something like 0.0.0.0:80 and :443

You will be able to see the Process ID (PID) that i using that port.

Also to troubleshoot SSL, you can run in the same command prompt "netsh http show sslcert" and you should see in there the certificate you assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging info.  I've been away for a while and returned to this today and it all seems to be working as expected.  I guess on the day I originally tried this something was blocking the port (perhaps Skype because I do have it installed).  If I experience this issue again, I'll use the steps listed here.

Comment: I had the same issue. I had to quit Skype, then restart it after I had added the binding and started the Default Web Site, then it worked.